# Rewrite rule for wordpress returns wrong query value

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting

I'm trying to add a new rewrite rule to my wordpress plugin. I like to display custom contents on a specific page.

If the user visits the URL

> example.tld/konzerte/143/

it should be overwritten to

> example.tld/index.php?pagename=konzerte&event-id=143

So on plugin activation I call the add_rewrite_rule function with the following code:

```
add_rewrite_rule ('konzerte/?([^/]*)', 'index.php=?pagename=konzerte&event-id=$matches[1]', 'top');
```

But when I'm reading the content of "event-id" by get_query_var('event-id') it only returns me a string with the content "$matches[1]".

Did I miss something I also have to do in the add-function?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the id is a number why are you using that regex and not `([0-9]+)`?
(https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule#Basic_Usage).

Comment: I tried this one but it didn't work. So I used the above as a test to accept every kind of value.